# Logged in with Wrong User

Tags: sharepoint-server

Today one of our business user has reported strange issue, He logged into his machine using his windows credentials but when he open our Intranet Portal(which is built on SP 2013) he can see his colleague name as logged in user. he logged out but again when he open our Intranet it open with his colleague name only.

We restarted machine, Deleted his colleague profile from that machine but still whenever we open Intranet Portal, its automatically logged in with his colleague name.

We checked in AD, Both accounts are different, and have different display name.But they are under same OU.

Any input to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a browser caused issue. Clear browser caches or change a browser to have a try.

Comment: This may also be a session issue with a load balancer or reverse proxy.

Comment: We have only single server and there is no Load Balancer, We tried clearing cache and remove all browser data but still same issue.

Comment: Does this happen when he logs in from a different browser? Did you try from a different machine?

Comment: We tried Chrome and IE same issue. Didn't tried from different machine.